# Tengo una Clase A con instancia de clase B y la clase B tiene una instancia de la clase A

Tags: java, diseño

Tengo dos clases que se necesitan mutuamente, es decir tengo una clase A con un objeto de la Clase B y en la Clase B tengo un objeto de la clase A.

¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

En particular:

Tengo una clase A que gestiona `beacons` (entrada y salida) y por otra parte tengo la clase B que gestiona el funcionamiento de un juego. Cuando llega un `beacon` (clase A), utiliza métodos del juego (clase B), por ejemplo `iniciarPartida()` y cuando ocurre un evento en el juego, por ejemplo finaliza la partida, envía un `beacon` a través de la clase que los gestiona que sería la clase B.

Lo que yo he pensado sería así:

```
public Class A{
  private B b;
  public A(B b){
      this.b = b;
      b.putA(this)
  }
  public void iniciarPartida(){
    ...
  }
  private finalizarPartida(){
    b.enviarBeacon(beacon)
  }
}


public Class B{
   private A a;
   public B(){
     a = null;
   }
   public void putA(A a){
     this.a = a;
   }
   public void beaconRecibido(Beacon beacon){
     if(beacon==xxx)
       a.iniciarPartida();
   }
   public void enviarBeacon(Beacon beacon){
     beacon.enviar();
   }
}
```

¿Esto estaría bien? Es que puede valer pero visualmente me parece muy feo... y no se si es lo mejor o lo correcto.

Comment: Podrias agregar mas contexto de lo que necesitas para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: He de decir también que esto lo necesito porque la Clase A necesita llamar a métodos de la clase B y viceversa.

Muchas gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: ¿No podrías crear una sola clase? En lugar de separadas

Comment: @jasilva gracias por responderme, ¿te sirve el comentario mío de encima? si no, te lo intento aclarar de la mejor manera posible.

Comment: Por ejemplo, puedes usar metodos estaticos con clases publicas para que A invoque de B y visceversa, pero depende de que sean las clases para determinar la mejor forma de hacerlo

Comment: Gracias por contestar Garrizano , no podría hacer eso porque una clase no tiene nada que ver con la otra. @jasilva A ver me explico un poco más, tengo una clase A que gestiona beacons (entrada y salida) y por otra parte tengo la clase B que gestiona el funcionamiento de un juego. Cuando llega un beacon (clase A), utiliza métodos del juego(clase B), por ejemplo iniciarPartida() y cuando ocurre un evento en el juego, por ejemplo finaliza la partida, envía un beacon a través de la clase que los gestiona, ¿?

Comment: José, lo mejor es poner un ejemplo del código que tienes donde se refleje el problema de diseño que tienes. Lo más probable es que si no lo tienes y te pones a crear el código tengas una solución para la situación. Y si no lo encuentras, pues igual ya tendrás algo que mostrar sobre lo que podamos explicar más.

Comment: @Jose ¿La mejor forma? **No** hacer eso. Es un [**mal diseño**](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references) y típicamente se le conoce [dependencia circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). La solución más rápida es [introducir una interfaz](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20110720033556/http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/07/17/breaking-dependency-cylces), aunque esto es un realmente paliativo.

Comment: Lo normal a la hora de hacer un videojuego (que parece tu caso) es que la clase `Juego` se encargue de gestionar todos los elementos que van a participar en el juego. Estos elementos incluyen la entrada y salida. Se trata básicamente de implementar el [game loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure) que lee la entrada, actualiza el mundo y emite la salida (pintar en pantalla). Esto lo hace normalmente a 60 veces por segundo o el refresco que necesites en el juego. Te recomiendo que utilices esa aproximación.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Awes0meM4n Efectivamente la clase juego la tengo como tú mencionas, el problema viene cuando del jugador no depende que comience la partida sino de otro jugador con su móvil, y al terminar la partida este debe notificarlo al jugador que le concedió el derecho de jugar. De ahí viene que tenga la clase una para el juego y otra para los beacons, que será el mensaje que enviará y recibirá el maestro cuando una partida pueda empezar o cuando esté acabada.

De nuevo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según lo leído yo crearía una 3 clase que se encargue de hacer todo eso, ademas de aplicar un *patron de diseño* tipo **Observador** de tal forma que la tercera clase sea la clase observadora y tus dos clases sean clases observables de esa forma cuando la clase a necesite ejecutar un método de la clase B primero mande una notificación a la tercera clase y esta la ejecute y de la misma forma para la clase B que le notifique a la tercera clase que necesita ejecutar un método de la clase A.

**Patron de Diseño Observador:**

El patrón de diseño consta de lo siguiente, un Objecto observador y Uno o unos objetos observables, los objetos observables van a notificar al objeto observable y este ultimo al ser notificado realizara alguna accion que tu programes. Su implementacion de la forma mas fácil es de la siguiente.

Primero necesitamos crear dos interfaces, el obersable y el observador.

```
public interface Observador {
    public void accionObservador();
    //Pueden ser mas metodos
}
public interface Observable {
        public void notificar();
   }
```

Ahora en tu caso se implementaria de la siguiente forma.

```
          public class C implements Observador{
    //Clase que maneja todo


    public C(){
        A claseA = new A(this);
        B claseB = new B(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void accionObservador() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Alguien me notifico aunque me pueden enviar un parametro para saber de que clase vino con un instance of y otro parametro
        //Para saber que haccion ejecutar de la otra clase
    }

}



      import java.util.ArrayList;

public class B implements Observable{

    private Observador miObservador;

    public B(Observador obj){
        this.miObservador=obj;

    }
    @Override
    public void notificar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Notifico a mi observador
        this.miOberservador.accionObservador();
    }


    private void saludar(){
        //La Accion saludar hace que se notifique a mi observador que voy a saludar
        //En tu caso voy a llamar a un metodo del A 
        notificar();
    }

}


    public class A implements Observable{

        private Observador miOberservador;
        public A(Observador ob){
            //Le indico quien me va a observa
            this.miOberservador = ob;
        }



        @Override
        public void notificar() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Notifico a mi observador
            this.miOberservador.accionObservador();
        }


        private void saludar(){
            //La Accion saludar hace que se notifique a mi observador que voy a saludar
            //En tu caso voy a llamar a un metodo del B 
            notificar();
        }

    }
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero según lo he entendido estaría en la misma situación ya que la "notificación" se haría a llamando desde la clase A o B a un método de la tercera Clase por tanto la tercera clase tendría que tener una instancia de la clase A y B las clases A y B una instancia de la tercera clase, así que sería lo mismo ¿no?

Comment: @Jose Con el patrón de Observador no es necesario que la clase A y B tenga una instancia de la tercera clase. Voy a actualizar mi respuesta para mostrarte como funciona el patrón de diseño.

Comment: @Jose Ya he actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo intento pillar y lo tengo cerca, pero no acabo de verlo claro. A ver si tú llamas desde la clase A (por ejemplo) a notificar() y dentro del notificar() tienes la llamada a la acción del observador, si en la acción del observador quieres llamar a un método de la clase B, en el observador tendrías que tener una instancia de la clase B, ¿no? por tanto si en la clase B tienes una instancia de Observador (miObservador) y en miObservador necesitas una instancia de la clase B para llamar a su método, ¿no tenemos el mismo problema?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Jose es correcto es que no instancie en la clase c la clase A ni B ya actualice el codigo revisa.

Comment: gracias por tus respuestas, ahora sí lo veo claro, pero tengo una duda y si la clase C es muy larga (en mi caso sería una activity de Android) tiene sentido hacer eso? Lo digo porque la clase A y B tendrían que contener esa activity. O sería mejor crearme los atributos A y B en la clase C y después en la clase de la Activity obtenerlos de la clase C?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JMR Lo mejro seria que la clase C sea aparte del activity es decir que la clase C no sea un activity, simplemente desde un activity tu la instancies. No olvides aceptar la respuesta en el chulo verde al lado de la votacion seria de gran ayuda para mi.

Answer (score 0):

Si los métodos son estáticos :

```
class A {
    public static void metodoA() {}
}

class B {
    public static void metodoB() {}
}
```

puedes llamarlos de la siguiente forma:

Creas la instancia de las clases y llamas los métodos directamente:

```
B b = new B();
b.metodoB()
```

Lo mismo al instanciar la clase A:

```
A a = new A();
a.metodoA()
```

---

**Actualización:**

El usuario al parecer desea realizar dependencia circular:

> Tengo dos clases que se necesitan mutuamente, es decir tengo una clase
>   A con un objeto de la Clase B y en la Clase B tengo un objeto de la
>   clase A.
>
> ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
```